# Change mongodb spatial reference

Tags: mongodb, spatial, geo

MongoDB uses the WGS84 datum for geospatial queries on GeoJSON objects. 
What should I do when my data is stored in other datum?
Can I create spatial index specifying datum or when making queries specify datum?

Best Regards,
Edijs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB does not support any other datum than WGS84 (and WGS84 is de facto standard these days). If your data uses different reference ellipsoid then I could only advise converting it to WGS84 before storing it in MongoDB if you would like to use geospatial features in MongoDB.

Here is somehow a related topic converting WGS72 to WGS84: [Converting between coordinates system WGS 74 and WGS 84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511094/converting-between-coordinates-system-wgs-74-and-wgs-84)

If this does not meet your app requirements then check out PostGIS.